# How to display text between two instances of same tokens in PHP

Tags: php

I read this things in one book to display text.
You can display the text by using the syntax echo<<here document.
This is my code :

```
<html>
    <head> </head>      
    <body>
        <h1> Here's what PHP has to say...</h1>
        <br />
<?php 
    echo <<<END
    This is example use of HERE document syntax to display all the text untill the ending token is reached END;
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

But after running this file it gives error:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or heredoc end (T_END_HEREDOC) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in C:\wamp\www\PHPpractice\phphere.php on line 12

So what is my mistake or how to run this..??

Comment: Big red warning: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Align of `END` should be left. Something like this

```
echo <<<END
    This is example use of HERE document syntax to display all the text untill the ending token is reached 
END;
```